# Roulette probability

Tags: probability

In a roulette game, a player bet only on the Red color (we are given that the probability of Red is 18/38). The player will stop playing after at least one winning or losing 11 rounds in a row. On the first game he bets \$1, in the 2nd game he bets \$2, and in the $i$th game he bets $2^{i-1}$. If he won, he will get the money that he bet on, else he lose the money he bet on.
(meaning that if he won/lost a game he can start a new round and bet from \$1 again)
 1. How much he will earn if he wins the $i$th game?
 2. What is the expected value of the number of rounds?

Comment: The house always wins.  See: http://www.amazon.com/The-Eudaemonic-Pie-Thomas-Bass/dp/0595142362/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1371772918&sr=8-1&keywords=eudemonic+pie

Comment: Which course is this homework for?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  try calculating the outcome of winning the first, second, third, fourth games.  The pattern should be clear, then prove it.  For the expected value, you need the chance he loses $11$ games in a row.  What is that?

Comment: i edited the question, i hope now it's more clear,
thanks ross!

Comment: @guestCS:  it was clear before.  Have you been able to make any progress given the hint?

Comment: with the first question yes, the 2nd no progress

Comment: If your probability for winning is $p$, the probability for losing is $q = 1-p$. Independent random events(such as your roulette example or throwing a dice), allow you to multiply the probabilities.$$$$
E.g. scoring 6 twice in a row with a dice has a probability of one out of six, times one out of six: $\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: the chance he lost a bet is 20/38, if he loses 11 rounds in a row that's 11*(20/38) so the expected value is ~5.798?

Comment: @guestCS:  No, losing $11$ in a row is $(\frac {20}{38})^{11}\approx 0.00086$  You multiply the chances.  So you have $0.99914$ chance of winning $1$ and that chance of losing ?